# Flickering issue when drawing div in Angular

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kzGHAJvQPlb2xgbaAdxk?p=preview) I have a div that needs to be drawn dragging the mouse. I'm using mouse up/move/down events. The problem that I have is that the div "flickers" when I drag down. How to fix this?

HTML

```
<style>
  .frame {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: orange;
      position: relative;
  }
  .sel{
     border:2px solid black;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     position:absolute;
  }
</style>
<div class="frame" ng-mousedown="mouseDown($event)" 
                   ng-mousemove="mouseMove($event)" 
                   ng-mouseup="mouseUp()">
  <div class="sel" ng-show="show"
       ng-style="{top:selTop+'px', left:selLeft+'px', width:selWidth+'px', height:selHeight+'px'}"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.startPoint = {};
     $scope.show = false;

     $scope.mouseDown = function(event) {
            $scope.startPoint = { x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY };
            $scope.show = true;
        };


       $scope.mouseMove = function(event) {
            if (!$scope.startPoint.x)
                return;
            $scope.selTop = $scope.startPoint.y;
            $scope.selLeft = $scope.startPoint.x;
            $scope.selHeight = event.offsetY - $scope.startPoint.y;
            $scope.selWidth = event.offsetX - $scope.startPoint.x;
       };

       $scope.mouseUp = function() {
            $scope.startPoint = {};
            $scope.show = false;
       };

});
```

Comment: it flickers because `event.offsetX` keeps changing, try using `event.pageX` or `event.clientX` with appropriate offset of your div, here is more about it: [mouse events](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/eventhandlers/mouseevents/)

Answer (score 0):

just add these css properties

```
border: none;
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 0 gray;
text-align: center;
&:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

see the plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/9WntGyBLQxYSxkFjDAy2/